# Meaning of the yum error "Package tuple (...) could not be found in rpmdb"

Tags: fedora, yum, rpm

I just want to install two packages in my Fedora 15 but I am getting some weird 
error.

**Command:**
`yum install @development-tools`

**Error:**

> Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit Setting up
>   Install Process Package flex-2.5.35-13.fc15.x86_64 already installed
>   and latest version Error: Package tuple ('gcc', 'x86_64', '0',
>   '4.6.0', '6.fc15') could not be found in rpmdb

**Command:**
`yum install fedora-packager`

**Error:**

> Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit Setting up
>   Install Process Error: Package tuple ('fedora-packager', 'noarch',
>   '0', '0.5.9.0', '1.fc15') could not be found in rpmdb

On first command  it says package already installed and latest version but why I got that error line.How to fix this errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like corrupt data. Do: `yum clean all` followed by `yum update` and then try the installation again.

Comment: does this commands affect my existing system?

Comment: It's the Yum equivalent of using `apt-get update` so all affects are positive.

Comment: only `yum clean all` solved my issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps you need to do a `rpm --rebuilddb` and check that no strange files are left in `/var/lib/rpm`. If there are `__db.xxx` files around, `db_recover` might be called for.

Comment: In my case a 'yum clean all' did the trick. The message I got was after using the 'fedup' program to update me from F17 to F19.

Answer (score 5):

You could try rebuilding the rpmdb

```
rpmdb --rebuilddb
```

This fixed a similar problem for me.

Comment: +1 - this sorted the issue for me, when `yum clean all` didn't.

Answer (score 5):

To solve that problem I had to do both:

```
yum clean all 
rpm --rebuilddb
```